# Как растянуть блок по высоте родителя если у родителя 100VH?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, html

Первый экран должен быть 100vh (в нем шапка + меню + первая секция)

Как сделать чтобы блок (first-screen) занимал всю оставшуюся высоту, если высота шапки и меню неизвестна ???

Необходимо использовать flex-box.
И у того, что должен занять оставшееся место flex-grow: 10 [например].

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="top-line"></div>
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="first-screen"></div>
</div>
```

---

Необходимо использовать flex-box.
И у того, что должен занять оставшееся место flex-grow: 10 [например].

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто)
Ваш блок `parrent` будет флекс контейнером и внутри него можно будет использовать правила разметки по флексбоксам.
Как вы и написали, вам поможет свойство `flex-grow: 1;` для блока, который должен занимать свободное пространство внутри флекс контейнера `parrent`.

Обратите внимание, что флекс контейнеру указано направление `flex-direction: column;`

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start
  align-items: stretch;
}

.first-screen {
  flex-grow: 1; 
}

/*Ниже декоративные стили*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-line {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.menu {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.first-screen {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="top-line">Шапка неизвестной высоты</div>
  <div class="menu">Менюха неизвестной высоты</div>
  <div class="first-screen">Этот блок будет занимать оставшееся место на первом экране</div>
</div>
```